# C# SSL connection could not be established in alpine docker container with .net 6 python.net

Tags: c#, python-3.x, docker, alpine-linux, wsl-2

I have a DLL that I made a while back for use in simplifying the sending of SOAP requests to one outdated API our company still uses today. The snippets below are from the C# source code of the DLL that still works on Windows and a local machine running WSL Ubuntu 22.04 as of today and returns the correct response, but produces error 'The SSL connection could not be established' on a docker container running Alpine despite having disabled server certificate checks (only for development):

C#:

```
    public static string soapRequest(string number, string planCode)
    {
        string transaction_key = generateTransactionKey();
        string url = "https://url.to.api/endpoint";

        string xmlSOAP = $@"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:foo=""http://api.provider/"">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
            ....
            </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>";

        try
        {
            var result = PostSOAPRequestAsync(url, xmlSOAP);
            result.Wait();
            return result.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }

    private static async Task<string> PostSOAPRequestAsync(string url, string text)
    {
        HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);

        using (HttpContent content = new StringContent(text, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"))
        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
        {
            request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", _authorization);
            request.Content = content;
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using Python.NET to be able to reference the library, with .NET 6 installed on the docker container. The Library is accessed but fails in the SSL check.

For testing, I am using the following python code:

Python:

```
from pythonnet import load
load("coreclr")
import clr
clr.AddReference("soapRequest")
from SR import soapRequest
sr = soapRequest()
print(sr.getResponse("1","TEST"))
```

And the error is:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
 ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
 ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I've been stuck on this problem for weeks now and am currently using a temporary workaround. If anybody can help me figure out why it works in both my Windows and Ubuntu copies but fails in a docker container, or point me in the right direction, it would be most appreciated. Just to clarify, it WORKS in both the Windows 11 and WSL Ubuntu 22.04 that I use, but only stops working when I try it on a docker container running on a base image python:3.9.6-alpine with .net 6 and python.NET installed.

Comment: I've had something similar that was due to mismatched TLS versions. One end wanted to talk TLS1.2 or better and the other end only wanted to do TLS1.0. I had to run Wireshark to see the details of the SSL handshake and why it failed.

Comment: Your SOAP service probably runs an old TLS version that .NET won't accept. This might be relevant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux